# Built a chloropleth map in R, but only first country in data frame has colour from bins/palette

Tags: r, maps

I've built a chloropleth map using the code below. The aim is to have a load of different countries showing in different shades of green (darker colours where health expenditure makes up a greater portion of GDP). However, when I run this code, a world map is generated where only Australia has any green colour on it. No other country seems to be changed. Australia is the first country in my data frame, so i assume this has something to do with the problem.

```
# individual mapping exercise
library(readxl)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

# import the dataset
health_eur <- read_excel("healthcare_expediture.xlsx")

# import shp
world <- readOGR("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL- 
0.3.shp")

# align entries in each dataset
is.element(health_eur$country, world$NAME)
health_eur$country[16] <- "Ireland"
health_eur$country[30] <- "Slovakia"
health_eur$country[27] <- "Korea, Republic of"
is.element(world$NAME, health_eur$country)
world <- subset(world, is.element(world$NAME, health_eur$country))

# move one vector around so they are in the same order
health_eur$country <- with(health_eur, 
health_eur[order(health_eur$country),])

# create bins and colour palette
bins <- c(2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 17.5, 20.0)
pal <- colorBin("Greens", domain = health_eur$health_exp, bins = bins)

# create chloropleth
map <- leaflet() %>%
  setView(0,0,0) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  addPolygons( data = world,
               smoothFactor = 0.5,
               color = "f6f6f6",
               fillOpacity = 0.95,
               fillColor = ~pal(health_eur$health_exp),
               highlight = highlightOptions(
                 weight = 7,
                 color = "#304ffe",
                 dashArray = "",
                 bringToFront = TRUE
               ))
map
```

Here is the map that is generated:

[image: world_map_health_expenditure]

Comment: Could you share your `healthcare_expediture.xlsx` file ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lbllmbaUaeUEHR-zqeQRu16SVG9xpnGJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For future reference, please do not share the excel file like this, as this question has nothing to do with excel.  Instead share the R data.frame (using `dput`), and delete any parts of the code that relate to importing this data from excel.  Try to keep your questions *minimal* as well as complete.

Comment: Apologies - won't happen again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved deleting `dashArray = ""` from `highlightOptions`.

```
map <- leaflet() %>%
  setView(0,0,0) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  addPolygons( data = world,
               smoothFactor = 0.5,
               color = "f6f6f6",
               fillOpacity = 0.95,
               fillColor = ~pal(health_eur$health_exp),
               highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
                 weight = 2,
                 color = "#304ffe",
                 bringToFront = TRUE
               ))
map
```

[image]